# Emacs: setting "comment-column" for all buffers

Tags: emacs

I am trying to set the `comment-column` local variable to 70 by default for every buffer I am opening.

I thought that the only thing I had to do is to put the following line in my `.emacs` file, and to reload Emacs:

```
(setq-default comment-column 70)
```

However, when I restart Emacs, it is still to set to 40.

I also tried equivalent like:

```
(set-default 'comment-column 70)
```

I am obviously missing something obvious, but I can't find what. I think there is something I don't know about the local variables such as `comment-column`.

Comment: Works fine for me, and obviously you have a sufficiently-recent version of Emacs to have `setq-default` available or you'd see errors; so I can only presume something is subsequently setting a different value. Check that you don't have a value set via the `customize` interface, and being evaluated after your `setq-default`.

Comment: @phils weird. No I don't have such a thing. I also put it at the end of the `.emacs` file just in case and still the same. Will continue my debugging later today by removing parts of the code.. etc... until I hope seeing the error :)

Comment: Please start emacs with `emacs -Q` and try `M-: (setq-default comment-column 70)`. Open afterwards your test file and look what the value of `comment-column` is. Please, add which file you open to test the comment column to the problem description. This is important since the behaviour is mode-dependent (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I cite the help on `comment-column`:

> Documentation: Column to indent right-margin comments to. **Each mode
>   may establish a different default value for this variable; you can set
>   the value for a particular mode using that mode's hook.** Comments might
>   be indented to a different value in order not to go beyond
>   `comment-fill-column' or in order to align them with surrounding
>   comments.

Could the bold-faced part be the problem?

I have tried it at my place. There, most programming modes use the global default value whereas `modelica-mode` uses its own default value.

Comment: As far as I can see, the bold text is just a reference to the fact that this variable is defined as being automatically buffer-local. So it can have a distinct value on a per-buffer basis. Using a mode hook to set it would ensure that each of the relevant buffers got the *same* value (but if you then changed it in one buffer, it wouldn't affect the others). Normal buffer-local behaviour is what I'd expect here, in other words.

Comment: That said, yes, naturally any code which sets the variable will affect the value in those cases, but `C-h v` in such a buffer would tell you if the value was the *default* value, or a buffer-local value.